# Simple case of using Google Analytics for android doesn't works

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm having a really hard times using Google Analytics in my android application.

I don't need anything complicated, all I want to do is to receive general information about my users, and to receive reports whenever the application crushes.

I performed the following steps:

1. I created an Application class which contains a private Tracker object.
2. inside the onCreate function I initialized it.

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application{

       private Tracker googleAnalyticsTracker;
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();

           GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
           googleAnalyticsTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.google_analytics_tracker);
           googleAnalyticsTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
           googleAnalyticsTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);

       }
   }
   ```
3. I created an xml file in order to generate the tracker (google_analytics_tracker.xml), as you can see here:

   ```
   <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

   <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
   <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
   <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>


   <!-- The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
   <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-*THE ID WHICH I RECIVED*</string>
   ```

nevertheless - whenever I execute the application I can't see anything in my google analytics dashboard. Whenever the program crushes - I can't see anything in the google analytics Behavior/'crashes and exceptions' as wel.(I'm looking

does someone have a clue what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the instructions on this page. You are missing a few things such as sending a screen view event as well as any activity code to getting the global tracker

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/